# Changing HTTP_USER_AGENT with mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

we have a customer who has changed the windows registry in a way, that MSIE always show "MSIE 7.0b", although a more current version is installed.

Our web application needs at least MSIE 8. Therefore I'm trying to use mod_rewrite to change the value of HTTP_USER_AGENT:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond expr "%{HTTP_USER_AGENT} -strmatch 'MSIE 7.0b'"
RewriteRule .* - [L,E=HTTP_USER_AGENT:'MSIE 8']
#RewriteRule .* [L,E=HTTP_USER_AGENT:'MSIE 8']
#RewriteRule .* [L,E=HTTP_USER_AGENT::'MSIE 8']



* The apache2 configtest failed.
Output of config test was:
AH00526: Syntax error on line 2 of /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/rewrite.conf:
RewriteRule: bad flag delimiters
Action 'configtest' failed.
```

As you can see, I have tested differente versions of the RewriteRule, but I always get the same error.
Well, what is the right construction of the RewriteRule to change the setting of HTTP_USER_AGENT?

Thanks for any hints,

Stefan

Some progress: Changing the RewriteRules to

```
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_USER_AGENT:"MSIE\ 8"]
#RewriteRule .* - [E=User-Agent:"MSIE\ 8"]
```

removes the error message, but it doesn't change the version of MSIE. I also tried

```
BrowserMatch "MSIE 7\.0b" User-Agent="MSIE 8.0"
SetEnvIf User-Agent "MSIE 7\.0b" User-Agent="MSIE 8.0"
```

but wasn't successful either. Is it possible to change this variable at all?

Stefan

Comment: Deleting my original answer.  mod_headers will not work because that only modifies the response headers.  [E=..] will only set environment variables.  If you want this to work, your app will need to read environment variables instead of looking at headers.

Comment: It does work with mod_header! We extended the configuration and are now using proxy-balancer module, too. Since mod_header also modifies the header of a forwarded request, the line "RequestHeader edit User-Agent 'MSIE 7\.0b' 'MSIE 8.0'" solves the problem.

Comment: In that case, I'll undelete my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Using E=... in mod_rewrite changes environment variables not http headers.  If you want to change http headers you will need to use mod_headers.  Here is the documentation:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_headers.html